# Would you be given more than 200 reputation points back if you were serially downvoted?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Say you have been serially downvoted today and lost 210 reputation from it. Tomorrow, the reversal kicks in and

- Would you be given the 210 rep points back or 200 only because of [daily limit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)?
- If you are given the 210 back—would it count towards the [Mortartboard](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard), [Epic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/145/epic) and [Legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary) badges?

Comment: Consider that there are voting limits, so even if a serial downvoter used them all, it is unlikely to be close to 200 ;) - you seem to be asking if the reputation "gain" from serial voting reversals is excluded from the rep cap (which it is - the deletion of such votes makes them be as if they never happened).

Comment: They've been consistently reversed, little reason to assume it won't happen again.  Given the repetition, it is certainly time to flag a moderator about this.

Comment: Why would it? What you see on your account page can be thought of as an annotation of what occurred. If you go to your reputation audit page (/reputation), you will not see any votes/reputation - that page tells it as it is for the purposes of badges/repcap.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Voting reversal doesn't add rep equal to the amount lost, per se; rather it recalculates reputation *as if the votes had never been cast in the first place*, at least for purposes of rep cap calculations.  The entries in the reputation *log* don't appear that way, in that the original vote's rep change is still shown, with a corresponding rep change at a later date, but this is merely so that you can see what actually happened.

This means that rep cap for reversed down votes is not considered by the rep cap on the day that the vote is reversed.  If, however, you reached the rep cap on the day that you were actually downvoted and, as a result, didn't actually lose rep, then when the vote is reversed you won't gain any rep.

The same concept applies when someone manually undoes their own vote.