# Jon Skeet's reputation +51 in a day he got enough votes to reach at least 200?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Going through the [User Reputation League for this week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2016-09-05) I got surprised that Jon Skeet wasn't on the first page. Then I noticed that [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=summary)'s reputation graph shows a rather strange situation: he did not reach the reputation cap on Sunday 4, where he just got 51 points.

However, if we go through [his reputation from that day](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation&sort=graph) we notice he got upvotes enough to reach 200.

Let's see what happened:

- he got 5 upvotes to not-community wiki answers. This gives 50 points.
- he got +5 for upvotes in many of his questions. I count 25 of them, one not giving +5 because it was to a CW question. This gives 120 points. In total, 170.
- some voting was reversed at 3 AM (-180). Probably the one in the previous bullet. This gives 170-180=-10.
- from that moment on, some upvotes were considered out of the cap, so they counted, but others did not. Also, he got two answers accepted. This gives -10+30+2*15=50
- he also got a +1, I guess that was coming after he downvoted an answer, so that his -1 would then lower the cap and allow a +1. This gives 50+1=51.
- all the way until midnight, he kept receiving (a lot of) upvotes, but +51 was the only he got.

Out of curiosity, the last time he did not reach the cap was on... June 6, 2010 - 145 rep! More than six years ago!!!

Comment: Well... July 19th this year looks like a non-rep cap. Maybe Jon is just bored of rep-capping and likes a change of scenery occasionally? :p

Comment: @NinjaPuppy ouch... I missed that one while going back in the graph!

Comment: I suspect the problem was the vote reversal. I noticed that as it happened - but in my rep audit, I see `-- 2016-09-04 rep +230  = 891272`. On July 19th I hit the cap too: `-- 2016-07-19 rep +200  = 880890`. So yes, I suspect it's an accounting difference somewhere.

Comment: Haha, first world problems: Meta post about a user _not_ hitting the rep cap.

Comment: The only real question here is why you are stalking Jon Skeet. How could you possibly notice what happens to *other people's* reputation?

Comment: @CodyGray err? Because his profile is public maybe? ;)

Comment: @NinjaPuppy I second that! He simply [did not want to have a nice day.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83lcOzMm_Tc)

Comment: @CodyGray I'm sure you are not serious, but still, I think we can safely assume that *everybody* sooner or later has a look at Jon's rep. It's just natural curiosity.

Comment: I few days ago, I was thinking it's impossible to catch up with Jon. Now the hope is back

Comment: I'm confused. For me it's showing Jon as getting 231 rep on the date you mentioned. (September 4). Was this just a temporary issue that's fixed itself now?

Comment: There should probably be a guess-which-day-Jon-Skeet-hits-1,000,000 contest. I also wonder what [se] has in store for Jon once he does hit it.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ We could do that next year instead of guessing how many peanut M&M's are in a jar during the Dev survey

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ 1,000,000 rep unlocks the privilege to permanently re-open your closed questions.

Comment: @Aaroninus: Jon Skeet has only 1 closed non-wiki question!

Comment: @NinjaPuppy June 19th is rep-capped, it just has a -15 due to an unaccept.

Comment: @JonSkeet you must get so bored of these notifications where you get mentioned. But here's another one to add to your day I guess. That's right - there's no real reason for this comment either. Sorry.

Comment: i think stackoverflow shud gift a Ferrari to jon skeet.

Comment: @FabioTurati: Speak for yourself; I honestly couldn't give a damn.

Comment: What @LightnessRacesinOrbit said. I know how the "Hot Post" box works but it feels a bit awkward that a post about someone's public persona made it there, especially since it was created by someone else.

Comment: @alexsome to be fair, Jon's account hits a lot of edge cases. Keeping tabs on him is pretty much akin to making a fake account you max out every day to test the upper limits of the site. There's a [whole](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284176/profile-display-gets-cut-off-for-users-with-lots-of-badges) [lotta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307439/jon-skeet-has-too-many-badges) [times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351797/jon-skeet-has-too-many-badges-again) where his account's shown us a bug before a "typical" user would run into them.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not actually sure what situation you're talking about, as for me Jon Skeet's reputation graph shows him earning 231 rep on that day:

[image: 231 rep earned on September 4, 2016]

That said, vote reversals count rep [as if the votes had never happened in the first place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269083/1157054). So if several of the reversed votes occurred on dates earlier than September 4, they would count against the rep cap for those days, not for September 4.

So if, for example, Jon Skeet earned 400 rep on Saturday before the cap, then earned 300 rep on Sunday before the cap, and then 180 rep was lost from reversed votes that occurred on Saturday, the graph might show 200 (300 capped to 200) - 180 = 20 rep earned on Sunday (though again, I'm not seeing this on my computer), when in fact what actually happened was that 200 (300 - 180 = 220, capped to 200) rep was earned on Saturday and 200 (300 capped to 200) was earned on Sunday.

Comment: When Jon Skeet makes less than 200 rep in a given day, every mod and SO dev is notified so they can correct the problem.

Comment: @Machavity Said notification takes the form of the site going down.

Comment: I suspect that it was all corrected by me going to the rep audit... or just a regular periodic correction. This morning, looking at my profile in the reputation tag (the voting record view, not the graph) it did indeed show a small amount for Sunday.

Comment: What @JonSkeet says. It is a pity I did not make a screenshot, but it was the way I describe it in my question.

Comment: See it happening again: http://i.stack.imgur.com/m7iO7.png